# Groovy not reading jar files in .groovy/lib

Tags: jdbc, groovy, classpath

I'm having a problem with jar files and groovy.  For a few specific examples I'm trying to connect to a postgresql database and when using 
`sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:postgresql://localhost", "user", "pass", "org.postgresql.Driver")`
I get a ClassNotFound exception for org.postgresql.Driver.  I have the postgresql jar in my ${user.home}/.groovy/lib, and the line to load from there in the groovy-starter.conf is not commented out.  I'm also having a similar problem with a dbunit.jar file.

If I try to manually add the classpath using groovy -cp I'm getting an error that says
`Caught: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: p`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the `java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the CLI Help - http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+CLI:

```
$groovy -help
usage: groovy
 -a,--autosplit <splitPattern>   automatically split current line
                                 (defaults to '\s')
 -c,--encoding <charset>    specify the encoding of the files
 -e <script>               specify a command line script
 -h,--help                 usage information
 -i <extension>            modify files in place
 -l <port>                 listen on a port and process inbound lines
 -n                        process files line by line
 -p                        process files line by line and print result
 -v,--version              display the Groovy and JVM versions
```

`groovy -cp` will tell `groovy` to load characterset `p` which does not exist.

Your attempt to use `${user.home}/.groovy/lib` should have worked assuming you used the correct path for `${user.home}`. If you add info on your OS we might see if you got it right or not.

As a WA - just export the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to wherever the jars are located.

**Windows:** `set CLASSPATH=c:\temp\postgresql.jar;c:\temp\dbunit.jar ...`
**Unix/Linux (KSH):** `export CLASSPATH=${HOME}/temp/postgresql.jar:${TEMP}/temp/dbunit.jar ...`